# i have an error when installing django with docker even though it is in accordance with the documentation

Tags: python, django, docker

how can I get to run django correctly by using docker? i have followed the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) but have an error like this[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEJk2.png)

Comment: Please post the coe as text not an image.

Answer (score 1):

The message is clear: you have another application using port 8000 on your machine (the host).

Try binding to a different port or shutting down the application using that port.

For example:

```yaml
ports:
      - "8888:8000"
```

where 8888 is your new host port.